# run from Shell R function with json string parameter

Tags: json, string, r, shell, parameters

I have function, that works with json string.
When I try in R:

```
 my_function('{"menu":{"id":"file","value":"File","popup":{"menuitem":[{"value":"New","onclick":"CreateNewDoc()"},{"value":"Open","onclick":"OpenDoc()"},{"value":"Close","onclick":"CloseDoc()"}]}}}')
```

it works well.

But when I try in Shell command:

```
 R -e "source('./my_function.R'); my_function('{"menu":{"id":"file","value":"File","popup":{"menuitem":[{"value":"New","onclick":"CreateNewDoc()"},{"value":"Open","onclick":"OpenDoc()"},{"value":"Close","onclick":"CloseDoc()"}]}}}')"
```

It fails with error:

> **unexpected character 'm'**

.

Seems, that problem is with quotes in json string. How can I solve it?

P.S. I need to call my_function directly from Shell.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Write it main script like main.r,

```
source('./my_function.R')
my_function('{"menu":{"id":"file","value":"File","popup":{"menuitem":[{"value":"New","onclick":"CreateNewDoc()"},{"value":"Open","onclick":"OpenDoc()"},{"value":"Close","onclick":"CloseDoc()"}]}}}')"
```

Execute it from command terminal like,

```
Rscript main.r
```

please make sure you have R path configured.

Comment: I know, that there are other ways, to run function: for example I can read from json file. But unfortunately, I need to run my_function directly from Shell.

Comment: can you give me your function def if its not confidential, so that I'll try on my side and let you know?

Comment: actually, this function is very complicated, because works with database and other functions. You can try on your side by writing simple function:

my_function<-function(string) return(string)


     Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix the quotes as you are doing. The shell is reading from your opening double quotes until the first double quotes it finds ( which is in your JSON string). It then sees an m (in menu) which it can't handle and gives the error message.

Comment: I understand, but maybe is there any way, to solve this problem?

Comment: Is the way in @Nachiket's answer not a possibility for you?

Comment: unfortunately no. There are many possibilieties. But I need to run my_function directly from Shell

Comment: Try escaping the double quotes `\"`.