# Run R function with string parameter from Shell, PHP or Java

Tags: java, php, r, shell

I have an R function with my_string parameter. In my case, parameter my_string is a very long json string, with many quotes.

```
my_function<-function(my_string) return(my_string)
```

When I run it from R:

```
 >my_function('string"with"quotes')
[1] "string\"with\"quotes"
```

It works well. But when I try to run this function from Shell:

```
R -e "source('./my_function.R'); my_function('string"with"quotes')"
```

It fails with error, because shell can't deal with quotes.

I need to run this function directly with json string parameter.
If it is impossible to do this from Shell, maybe there are other ways to run R function from PHP or Java with string, that contains quotes?

P.S. I know, that in Shell I can escaping the double quotes with \", and it will work, but json string is very long, therefore I can't do it manually every time.

Comment: Have you tried `R -e "source('./my_function.R'); my_function('string\"with\"quotes')"` ?

Comment: Where is the JSON string coming from? Are you cut n pasting it into the command line? Otherwise there must be a way of automatically escaping the quotes. Or write the JSON to a file and modify your function or write a wrapper to read from the file. Or a pipe.

Comment: @Spacedman, thank you for advises. I don't know yet, from where json will come. I'm writing an API, which will be used by someone else. I should find easy ways (servers) from where anyone would be able to run function directly with json

Comment: It looks like you are still fighting for using function from terminal. Is there any specific reason of not using Rscript or a json file?

Comment: @Nachiket, yes, I'm still in search. As I've written above, it's an API function, it will be using by other people and I should find easy way, to do that directly with json string. There would be huge stream of different json strings, therefore it's uncomfortable every time create new Rscript or json file.

Comment: If you are writing an API then your API function should take unescaped JSON, escape it, and then feed it to R.

Comment: It's not proper to escape so many quotes.

Comment: Therefore I'm asking for the other servers usage(PHP, Java).

Comment: PHP and Java aren't servers, they are languages. How is the JSON going to be put into PHP or Java anyway? Most languages need some way of quoting strings, otherwise how do they tell if a character is an end-of-string marker? This is all very unclear.

Comment: Isn't it possible to run R function from PHP or Java, without escaping each quote?

Comment: PHP and Java use quotes to make strings, to call R from PHP or Java will need you to pass that JSON to an R command as a string, which means escaping the quotes. So you are back at the same problem as the shell.

Comment: Spacedman, thank you a lot for information!

Comment: possible duplicate of [run from Shell R function with json string parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221113/run-from-shell-r-function-with-json-string-parameter)

Comment: You have asked at least [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22225253/run-from-shell-r-function-with-parameter-that-contains-quotes?rq=1) [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221113/run-from-shell-r-function-with-json-string-parameter?rq=1) questions about this, and have received excellent answers. Please do not repost the same question.